# Error executing remote commands with ssh using sudo user

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, remote-execution

The following command is failing:

```
ssh -t user@server-01 sudo -iu suser "cd /opt/jboss ; ./portal.sh stop"
```

I getting:

```
bash: ./portal.sh: No such file or directory
```

How can I change directory remotely and execute a remote command in that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
ssh -t user@server-01 sudo -iu suser "eval 'cd /opt/jboss ; ./portal.sh stop'"
```